# Use the php that comes with zend server from the command line on Mac

Tags: php, command-line, zend-server-ce

I have installed zend server on my mac and i think that there are two installations of php on my mac (i hate mac bythe way, i'd love to get back to windows 7), i think that a script i'm running from the command line (phpcs) is using the php command that is inside /usr/bin/ while i'd like to use the one that's inside /usr/local/zend/bin/ always. How should i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add /usr/local/zend/bin to your PATH, before /usr/bin.

Or just uninstall the PHP in /usr/bin.

Comment: how do i uninstall it?If i understand correctly this comes with the standard distribution.

Comment: Heh sorry, no idea, I'm not a Mac guy. At the least, you could rename it to /usr/bin/php.old or something.

Comment: Me neither, in the end i renamed the old php and made a simbolic link in /usr/bin/php to zend server php

Comment: There is no need to uninstall the default PHP...just ensure that you "prepend" /usr/local/zend/bin to your $PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

On Mac or Linux you can add the following to your bash shell (via `~/.bash_profile` or similar):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/zend/bin:$PATH
source /etc/zce.rc
```

Loading in `/etc/zce.rc` sets up the system library path correctly and removes warnings about the crypto lib.